# Why strings are stored in the following way in PE file

Tags: compilation, reverse-engineering

I opened a .exe file and I found a string "Premium" was stored in the following way

50 00 72 00 65 00 6D 00 69 00 75 00 6D 00

I just don't know why "00" is appended to each of characters and what's its usage.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a UTF-16 encoding of a Unicode string. Here's an example using Python:

```
>>> u"Premium".encode("utf16")
'\xff\xfeP\x00r\x00e\x00m\x00i\x00u\x00m\x00'
#        ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^    ^
```

After the byte marker to indicate endianness, you can see alternating letters and null bytes.

---

`\xff\xfe` is the byte-order marker; it indicates that the low-order byte of each 16-bit value comes first. (If the high-order byte came first, the byte marker would be `\xfe\xff`; there's nothing particularly meaningful about which marker means which.)

Each character is then encoded as a 16-bit value. For many values, the UTF-16 encoding is simply the straightforward unsigned 16-bit representation of its Unicode code point. Specifically, 8-bit ASCII values simply use a null byte as the high-order byte, and its ASCII value as the low-order byte.

Comment: I don't understand how '\xff\xfeP\x00r\x00e\x00m\x00i\x00u\x00m\x00' is "Premium", would you be kind enough to explain?